# How do I split up geometry without any gaps?

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects, layers

I'm trying to better organize my scene and I'd like to split up my geometry into some parts. However, there always remains a gap in between the parts and I don't get why. Of course, I can easily join the separate objects together into a single object and render the object as a whole:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can it be that it is simply not possible to keep components of meshes separate? I can not find a way to do that properly but I'm sure there is a way. What am I do wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123803/discussion-on-question-by-laz007-how-do-i-split-up-geometry-without-any-gaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you disable any *Smooth* modifier on your objects. It will effectively "shrink" the borders of the mesh, creating gaps in disconnected islands.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to everyone that responded >>> Removing the 'smooth' modifier, solved everything... I would have never solved this on my own... Thanks again :) --> huge thank you to @Gorgious for the fix

Comment: @Laz007 Note you can use vertex groups in the smooth modifier if you really want to smooth the rest of the mesh, you can work out a gradient with 0 weight on the border to keep it in place, and a gradual increase in weight over a few edge loops. Cheers

Comment: > I have used the 'face smooth' with the 'Face select' tab on.... I didn't know there was a gradient weight smoothing available >>> I'll definitely try this out... it's nice to have some more defined edges... I was using the pinch and crease tool to get some edging back again... thanks again